# Why is KeyPairGeneratorSpec throwing InvalidAlgorithmParameterException on API < 24

Tags: android, android-keystore, key-pair

When I'm using this KeyPairGeneratorSpec object in API 24, my class works.

```
KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(this)
                    .setAlias(KEY_ALIAS)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + KEY_ALIAS))
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
                    .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                    .build();
            KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA);
            kpg.initialize(spec);
            keyPair = kpg.generateKeyPair();
```

When compiling on lower than 24, I get this error:

```
java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: Only RSAKeyGenParameterSpec supported
```

I don't understand, as KeyPairGeneratorSpec should be available from api 18?

Comment: Same problem here, did you find an (elegant) way to fix this?

Comment: @Xvolks I don't remember well how I fixed it, can you try adding this parameter to the getInstance method? : KeyPairGenerator kpg = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(RSA, ANDROID_KEYSTORE);private static final String ANDROID_KEYSTORE = "AndroidKeyStore";

Answer (score 5):

Had this problem earlier today as well with the Pixel emulator (API 23) raising an "Only RSAKeyGenParameterSpec supported" exception, while a Nexus 5X (API 24) was fine.

Can confirm that the fix was to add 'AndroidKeyStore' as the second parameter to the call to getInstance on KeyPairGenerator as @estoke mentioned above:

ie:

`KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");`

Comment: I wonder why the same error happens to me on an API 29 emulator. It makes no sense to implement a solution that would be designed for API 23 and lower... Not sure what's going on.